# Is there a way to substitute a prefix and suffix with regular expressions?

Tags: regex, replace, ide

I'm trying to search and replace several commands in my code using an IDE's replace function with regex.

The functionality I'm looking for is this:

**Original text:**

```
AbbbC
AfffffC
AasdffdsaC
```

I want to replace *A* and *C* with *D* and *E* respectively but keep whatever was in the middle.

**Replaced text:**

```
DbbbE
DfffffE
DasdffdsaE
```

Is this possible in an IDE where I can find something by regex and then substitute part of that regex (I suppose the `'.'`) in the replace box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a captiure group to capture the part you want to copy into the replacement.

Replace:

```
A([^C]*)C
```

with:

```
D$1E
```

`$1` gets replaced with the part of the original string that matched the capture grop.